# How to get multiple TemplateRef from template reference variable？

Tags: angular

```html
<ng-template #customHeaderTemplate let-param>
   ...
</ng-template>

<ng-template #customHeaderTemplate let-param>
   ...
</ng-template>

<app-my-component [inputTemplate]='customHeaderTemplate'></app-my-component>
```

I want put parent multiple `TemplateRef` into child component, however the above code get `TemplateRef`, expected is `QueryList<TemplateRef>`.

In my case, I **don't** want use ViewChildren.

```
@ViewChildren('customHeaderTemplate') customHeaderTemplates: QueryList<TemplateRef>;
```

So, is here has a method to get `QueryList<TemplateRef>` value directly from html?